# Protecting a web app from unwanted vulnerability scanners

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I have a web application and I keep getting unwarranted offers from "security experts" and the results I get are pretty convincing. Somehow, they send me a report of PHP files running and ways on how to fix them.

The scans are using Acunetix and BeyondTrust software.

Is there a method I can use to protect my web application from such unwanted scans?

Comment: Fix the vulnerabilities?

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. If your goal is to make sure that these vulnerabilities (which you yourself find convincing) go way then you must fix the application which shows the vulnerabilities. If you instead just don't want to get pointed out that you have vulnerable software just delete the reports without taking a closer look at the problems. Of course, fixing the problems is the proper way to do since there is no vulnerability scanner actually needed to find and exploit the problems - it only makes it simpler.

Comment: Acunetix offer a free trial of their scans. Otherwise, you can use a free software tool like OWASP zaproxy and do your own scans and look into the issues. Otherwise, so long as the web application is Internet facing and does not require authentication, it can be scanned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a method i can use to protect my web application from such unwanted scans to my web application?

You can protect your web application by:

- using secure coding practices,
- diligently patching software,
- implementing a Web Application Firewall,
- regular approved scanning of the type offered by these 'security experts' (and remediation of their findings),
- Application Security Testing,
- (not an exhaustive list.)

Note that in these cases you'll *still* get scanned - both by these 'security experts', who are contacting you after the fact, and by the 'hackers', who you don't know about because they haven't contacted you.

As long as your application is on the Internet, it'll get scanned.  Constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: No.

Long Answer: It is on the internet so anyone can do whatever they want to it. Put the sites behind a firewall and limit to internal clients, leave it outside but require auth, or fix the vulnerabilities.

Comment: I understand. So basic php auth for instance in php would deny scanners access?

Comment: Hey Gandalf - It would deny them from getting access to the content of the page. Which would not allow the scanners to be able to audit page content vulns. They'd still be able to see if your web server (i.e. nginx) was configured wrong, etc. But requiring auth is a great start.